# How to solve make-file 's recipe of target 'run failed error?

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, mingw

I am trying to work on an opengl project using Visual Studio Code.
but it is not working..
when I try using this makefile ~

```
CC      := g++
CFLAGS  := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g
CPPFLAGS += $(CINCLUDES)

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

LIBRARIES   := -lglad -lglfw3dll

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
EXECUTABLE  := main.exe
SOURCEDIRS  := $(SRC)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(INCLUDE)
LIBDIRS     := $(LIB)
else
EXECUTABLE  := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
endif

CINCLUDES   := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))
CLIBS       := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))

SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))
OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -$(RM) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    -$(RM) $(OBJECTS)


run: all
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDES) $(CLIBS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)
```

I get this error when i run mingw32-make run

```
g++  -Iinclude  -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude -Llib src/main.o -o bin/main.exe -lglad -lglfw3dll
./bin/main.exe
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'run' failed
mingw32-make: *** [run] Error -1073741515
```

and even if I dont use this make file and directly use this command

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude -Llib src/main.cpp -o bin/main.exe -lglad -lglfw3dll
```

I get this error

```
src/main.cpp: In function 'void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int)':
src/main.cpp:77:44: warning: unused parameter 'window' [-Wunused-parameter]
   77 | void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

My Project Directory 
[image: My Project Directory]

I was following LearnOpengl Tutorial..
please help ..
how to solve these errors..
`Thanks`

Comment: `src/main.cpp:77:44:blah blah blah` isn't going to halt compilation or execution. It looks like you got an executable, but `./bin/main.exe` didn't successfully run. -1073741515 converts to C0000135 hex, and C0000135 means the exe couldn't find a dll it needed. What dll or why, I don't know.

Comment: Duhhrrr. Odds are good the missing DLL is ./lib/glfw3.dll. You probably want that in the path somewhere, but if you open a command prompt to the ./lib folder and then run ../bin/main.exe the program should run.

Comment: i got it running glfw3.dll was missing.. thanks